# Is process priority inherited?

Tags: windows, inheritance, process, windows-task-scheduler

Imagine that you have a Windows process A running with priority AboveNormal that starts another process B without specify the priority. Is the priority of the process B inherited from the priority of the process A? So, what will be the priority on the process B? AboveNormal, Normal, or another?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If not specified, the priority class **is** inherited, in **some** cases.

It occurs when the calling process is in the **IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS** or **BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY** class. Otherwise, it gets **NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS** unless specified during the CreateProcess call.

MSDN says on dwCreationFlags of CreateProcess:

> This parameter also controls the new process's priority class, which
>   is used to determine the scheduling priorities of the process's
>   threads. For a list of values, see GetPriorityClass. If none of the
>   priority class flags is specified, the priority class defaults to
>   NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS unless the priority class of the creating
>   process is IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS or BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS. In this
>   case, the child process receives the default priority class of the
>   calling process.

The answer is therefore NORMAL priority class. Basically anything that is above normal doesn't get passed to the child.

Comment: "Basically anything that is above normal doesn't get passed to the child." - What a tragic realization.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx):

> dwCreationFlags [in]
>
>     The flags that control the priority class and the creation of the process. For a list of values, see Process Creation Flags.
>
>     This parameter also controls the new process's priority class, which is used to determine the scheduling priorities of the process's threads. For a list of values, see GetPriorityClass. If none of the priority class flags is specified, the priority class defaults to NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS unless the priority class of the creating process is IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS or BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS. In this case, the child process receives the default priority class of the calling process.

So, in your example, the new process would have normal priority.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows process priority is not inherited.