How to set a lower priority for scikit-learn parallel processes spawned by n_jobs?
When using the n_jobs parameter to parallelize scikit-learn routines (like GridSeachCV), is there a way to set the parallel processes to a below-normal priority?
Often I would like to take maximum advantage of parallelization while still allowing concurrent use of my machine for regular computing tasks. I'm using Windows; opening Task Manager to manually set the priority to below normal for each of the spawned processes for n_jobs=-1 works well, but is very tedious.
Setting n_jobs to less than the available CPU threads or cores isn't quite a satisfactory solution, because my machine responds slowly to regular tasks unless I reserve at least two physical CPU cores (e.g., n_jobs=6 on an 8-core 16-thread CPU), which leaves many threads underutilized, and I would like all threads to be utilized when I am not concurrently using my machine.
I found this answer to a question about lowering the process priority of child processes using the psutil.Process() class.
The following code mostly works:
import psutil

# parallel processing for GridSearchCV.fit()
current_process = psutil.Process()
original_priority = current_process.nice()
current_process.nice(psutil.BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS)  # set parent priority
grid_search.fit(X, y)
current_process.nice(original_priority)  # reset parent priority

Here is a sample dataset and model to run the above code:
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# sample dataset
dataset = load_digits()
X, y = dataset.data, dataset.target

# sample model
rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=-1)
param_grid = {'max_depth': [x for x in range(5, 20)], 
              'min_samples_split': [x for x in range(2, 10)]}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(rf_model, param_grid, n_jobs=-1)

This code will usually allow grid_search.fit() to successfully spawn its parallel processes at below normal priority, but not always. Sometimes only some processes have below normal priority while the majority are normal, and for whatever reason I can't consistently reproduce that behavior. Also I'm not sure what the consequences are for setting the parent process to below normal priority (e.g. for interacting with a Jupyter Lab session or for stopping the kernel).
Is this the right way to go about setting a lower priority for scikit-learn parallel processes spawned by n_jobs? The scikit-learn docs on parallelism indicate that the n_jobs parameter uses joblib as its underlying implementation, but I didn't see anything about process priority in either set of docs.

My understanding of the joblib/loky source code is that it runs the CreateProcess function with dwCreationFlags set to 0, which means that the created processes inherit below normal priority of parent class, but does not inherit elevated priority. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619543/is-process-priority-inherited So I don't know why that would happen, unless the processes are being created prior to the priority change, and are just being kept around for some reason (re-using processes to avoid re-creating them?)

Source: https://github.com/joblib/loky/blob/2c21e44d50f235247443427c4714b5ffaa68c71d/loky/backend/popen_loky_win32.py#L86

@NickODell: Running the above code, the child processes nearly always correctly inherit the below normal priority from the parent, so I've concluded that it's "good enough" for me. In the rare cases where the child processes incorrectly ran at normal priority, I wonder if I did have a bunch of existing normal-priority processes sitting around from previous scikit-learn routines that just got re-used.

The best I've been able to do is put the psutil code in a context manager:
import psutil
from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager
def lower_process_priority():
    current_process = psutil.Process()
    original_priority = current_process.nice()
    try:
        current_process.nice(psutil.BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS)
        yield
    finally:
        current_process.nice(original_priority)

Usage:
with lower_process_priority():
   grid_search.fit(X, y)

This works fairly well to allow me to do regular computing tasks while scikit-learn is running in the background. Some applications respond better than others (oddly, Notepad++ is nearly unusable), but it's good enough.
One quirk I've found is that while running this code via Jupyter Lab in Firefox, the Jupyter Lab tab/process itself is often assigned a Low priority, which makes the Jupyer Lab tab nonresponsive. Using Task Manager to manually set the appropriate Firefox process to Normal works well (invoke about:processes in Firefox and find the process id in parenthesis).
